# Is 超 (chō) seldom used in written works?

Tags: words, usage, register, prefixes

Is it true that the prefix 超 to mean “very” is seldom used in written works (like novels, not counting direct speech), and is usually only used when talking?

Comment: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1110462891

Comment: It's definitely very colloquial and even slangish. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Pretty much depends on your definition of "written works", as I'm sure it is featured in every other page of any given issue of [Egg Magazine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_(magazine)) ;-) Aside from that: I would _never_ use it in any formal or semi-formal communication. In fact, even in speech, it tends to make you sound like a trashy teenage girl, so use with caution.

Comment: @Pacerier: as everyone else has pointed out (and I was joking about), the problem is that "written works" (even novels) can exist in any style. There are a whole bunch of contemporary Japanese novels written (afaik) in very colloquial Japanese. These do not make it any less colloquial. So your question makes more sense on a formal vs. colloquial scale (and the answer is: as colloquial as you can get without being outright rude ;-) [btw, did not get the notification for your comment]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what kind of written works you consider.

As Boaz wrote in a comment on the question, 超 (ちょう) meaning “very” is very colloquial.  It is highly unlikely to see it in formal contexts, written or spoken.

However, this does not mean that 超 (also written チョー or ちょー) is not used in written Japanese.  See latest search results on Google of ["超"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E8%B6%85%22&hl=ja&tbs=rltm%3A1), ["チョー"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%83%BC%22&hl=ja&tbs=rltm%3A1) and ["ちょー"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%83%BC%22&hl=ja&tbs=rltm%3A1) (but note that not everything in the results is this usage).

Comment: @Pacerier: sometimes writers, including Japanese ones, use [free indirect speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_indirect_speech) which means a completely conversational language can appear outside of quotation marks.

Answer (score 12):

We should also note that while 超- meaning "very" is colloquial, 超- meaning "super" or "above" (the "original" meaning of the kanji) is entirely acceptable as a prefix in a literary work.  In fact, many words rely on it:

> 超大国 【ちょうたいこく】 superpower, as in US or USSR during the Cold War (from WWWJDIC)

大国 is a word in its own right - 超- is just a prefix.

*EDIT:*

This answer was kind of an addendum, but has been upvoted a bit (thanks!).  I still agree with Tsuyoshi Ito's answer of "no you shouldn't use it in written works" as long as we're talking about the OP's meaning of "very".